# Why do we consider time complexity as O(Logn) if a matrix is powered by a constant value?

Tags: time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to think about it, and I don't get it.
If the matrix size is 1x1, than power by a constant = n is O(n).
If the matrix size is 2x2, than power by 2 goes like that:

```
|a b| X |a b|
|c d|   |c d|
```

=> a*a + b*c, a*b + b*d, c*a + d*c, c*b + d*d.
Multipication done was 8 times, addition - 4.
So 2X2 Matrix, goes to 8 MULT and 4 ADDs, overall -  12 calculations.
I don't see the connection to O(log n)?

Comment: What is `n`? Matrix size or power? If power, see [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Computational_complexity).

Comment: as I said, the matrix size is 1*1, so than you power it by number. If its from 1*1 size, its like multiplying a regular number like that: 5^3=5*5*5, in the same way: 5^n = 5*5*5...n times...5*5 => o(N) in time complexity

Comment: Then see the link above. `a^n` can be calculated in `log(n)` time.

Comment: Thanks! I will see it

Comment: For example, `5^8 = 25^4 = 625^2 = 390625` - just 3 multiplications, not 8.

Comment: Exactly. Matrix size will contribute to the prefactor of `log(n)`: if each matrix multiplication uses `K` scalar multiplications, the total number of scalar multiplications will be approximately `K log(n)`, which is still `O(log n)`.

Comment: It doesn't explain about matrix specifically. The sentence: "Each squaring results in approximately double the number of digits of the previous" seems as it doesn't count for powering matrix, as I showed that matrix from 2*2, do 8 Multipication, so if each squaring indeed approximately double the num of digits, its happening simulltaniously 8 times. it's seems like O(8logn) = O(log n)? if so, when you mult matrix, are you saying that the size of the matrix is a constant so it doesn't count in time complexity but as number? so actually you calculate it as number powered by a number complexity?

Comment: got it, thank a lot!